# Terraform: What are the conceptual differences between passing provider configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have providers.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "ap-northeast-1"
  allowed_account_ids = [local.one_account_id]
}

provider "aws" {
  alias               = "stg"
  region              = "us-east-1"
  allowed_account_ids = [local.one-account_id]
}
```

base/one.tf

```
1st way - deployed resources to us-east-1

module "one" {
  source = "../../modules/one"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.stg
  }
  resource_name_prefix                      = local.xxxx
}
```

2nd way = deploys resources to ap-northeast-1

```
module "one" {
  source = "../../modules/one"

  providers = {
    aws.stg = aws.stg
  }

  resource_name_prefix                      = local.xxxxx
}
```

module/one.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.20.1"
      # configuration_aliases = [aws.stg]
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = ">= 3.1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

What is the difference between passing `aws.stg = aws.stg` and `aws= aws.stg`?

Answer (score 0):

If your module needed more than one provider, like if it needed to access two separate AWS regions, or two separate AWS Accounts, then you would need to use the `configuration_aliases` method to distinguish the two (or more) providers being configured on the module. Otherwise, just use the method without an alias.